# how do I create a hash who's values come from any array?

Tags: perl

I have a hash with keys and now I want to fill the values of the hash from an array .

```
my %hash = ( key1 => "" , key2 => "")
my array = (1 ,2)
```

Desired output

```
my %hash = ( key1 => 1 , key2 => 2)
```

Comment: You didn't tried even single line coding?

Comment: How do you know which array elements map to which keys? Hashes are unordered.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [hash slice](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html):

```
my %hash = ( key1 => "" , key2 => "") ;
my @array = (1 ,2);

@hash{('key1','key2')} = @array;

print Dumper\%hash;
```

Output:

```
$VAR1 = {
      'key1' => 1,
      'key2' => 2
    };
```

You can't use the existing keys of the hash (`@hash{ keys(%hash) } = @array;`), because you could just as easily end up with `{ key1 => 2, key2 => 1 }` as the desired output.

Comment: Tip: `@hash{('key1','key2')}` can be written as `@hash{qw( key1 key2 )}`.